# Elasticsearch: automatic parameter propagation in documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have the following documents (containing logs) in Elasticsearch index:

```
PUT logs/_doc/1
 {
     "commonId" : "111111",
     "comment" : "abc",
     "phase" : "start"
 }

 PUT logs/_doc/2
 {
     "commonId" : "111111",
     "comment" : "cde",
     "customerNumber" : "234-333"
 }

 PUT logs/_doc/3
 {
     "commonId" : "222222",
     "comment" : "efg",
     "phase" : "stop"
 }

 PUT logs/_doc/4
 {
     "commonId" : "222222",
     "comment" : "jkl",
     "customerNumber" : "234-555"
 }
```

The thing which is common in all **logs** is **commonId** attribute.

**Problem is:**

I want process **logs** in a way:

- All logs with same commonId should exchange each other with **missing** attributes. So **log=1** should add **"customerNumber" : "234-333"**, and **log=2** should add **"phase" : "start"**. Same situation with logs=3 and 4.

Is it possible to do this by any Elasticsearch query? Generaly I'm not iterested in any paid option of X-Pack.